# How to set Luxon DateTime to start of day (reset time)

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

I have trawled the docs, but cannot find a a helper to reset the time of a Luxon DateTime.

I can start with a standard date:

```
export const getDateOnly = (date: Date = new Date()) =>  new Date(
  date.getFullYear(),
  date.getMonth(),
  date.getDate()
)

export const today = () => DateTime.fromJSDate(getDateOnly());
```

but this seems like a common scenario and I might have just missed it?

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof?

Comment: yes! just also found it and came back here :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reposting as answer for future reference.

https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof

With example:

```
export const today = () => DateTime.now().startOf('day');
```

Comment: it works with the plus function as well, so if you want to get tomorrow as a date, starting at 00:00:00 it will be like so: `const tomorrow = DateTime.now().plus({ days: 1 }).startOf('day');`

Comment: I would even say `DateTime.now().toUTC().startOf('day')` for the UTC start of today